# calling Spring's RequestPath from jsp:include

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl

I am using Spring 3.0.5
I am calling a controller from  tag like:

```
<jsp:include page="/getPageHeader">
    <jsp:param name="locator" value="" />
</jsp:include>
```

i need to do this coz i want to change header jsp page of current page according to requestParam.
The `/getPageHeader` controller checks the request URI and select appropriate header for page.

But this thing is giving me error:

```
Jun 28, 2011 2:01:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: PageContextImpl.release(): Internal error flushing buffer
Jun 28, 2011 2:01:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.ensureOpen(JspWriterImpl.java:204)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.clearBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:160)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB.includes.ourpartner_jsp._jspService(ourpartner_jsp.java:209)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:321)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:257)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:873)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I think this happens because Spring controller returns the header jsp page, which is already formatted.
Is there any better way to do this. Or any way to fix it.

**One more thing:**
When i am using tiles on the page where i am using that `jsp:include`, it is working fine. But when i am calling that page in `anchor<a>` tag, it shows me that error(which i have past).

Any help will be appreciable.
Thanks and regards

Comment: Hi, in my case i get an error in other location (JPA PostPersiste Listener) and the Spring give me the same error, I suggest you try to check something like this. I hope that i was help you.